# Как собрать из System. in слова в коллекцию Map и потом из мэп получить Stream

Tags: java

Хочу получить из System. in слова и посчитать с помощью коллекции мэп частоту вхождения и выводить рещультат. С начала создаю Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in) и а потос не понимаю надо из System. in получить с начала стрим или с System. in слова собрать в мэп и потом из мэп получить стрим и посчитать вхождения

Comment: `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines()`

Answer (score 0):

Читайте построчно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> yourMap = new HashMap();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String name = sc.nextLine();

            Integer number = yourMap.get(name);
            if (number == null) {
                number = 1;
            } else {
                number += 1;
            }
            yourMap.put(name, number);
        }

    }
```

Если нужно сделайте потом `split()`

Comment: В мэп как собрать значения?

Answer (score 0):

Со стримами все проще...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Data {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long> resultMap = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines()
                .flatMap(words -> Arrays.stream(words.split(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(resultMap);
    }    
}
```